# CCleaner app doesn't clear my Google Chrome browsing history

Tags: chrome-for-android

I did check the settings on my CCleaner app. The browsing history is selected for cleaning.

Is this because Chrome is a system app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, it seems like it doesn't because chrome stores history online if you are logged in with google account